# Django html display from model

Tags: python, django, django-views

I need on my html page to display data from Profesor and Ucenik model: ime, prezime, jmbg.

```
{{profesor.ime}}
{{profesor.prezime}}
{{ucenik.ime}}
{{ucenik.prezime}}
{{ucenik.jmbg}}
```

my profile page id dynamic, need to display profesor data or if ucenik to display ucenik data

what i need to add on my views.py

models.py

```
class Profesor(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ime = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
   prezime = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
 
class Ucenik(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ime = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
   prezime = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
   jmbg = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

urls.py

```
path('profesor/', views.profesor, name='profesor'),
path('ucenik/', views.ucenik, name='ucenik'),
path('posetioc/', views.posetioc, name='posetioc'),
path('profil/<str:pk>/', views.profil, name='profil'), ]
```

views.py

```
def profesor(request):

   return render(request, 'pocetna_profesor.html')


def ucenik(request):

   return render(request, 'pocetna_ucenik.html')


def profil(request, pk):

   return render(request, 'profil.html')
```

HTML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<title>profesor</title>

{% block content %}

<body>
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
   <h1>Ime:</h1>
   {{profesor.ime}}
</body>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please bring more focus to your question. Are you asking how to make a generic view and a generic template able to render a page no matter whether one model was requested or another? Are you asking how to build a [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-display-views) from the beginning, in general, like "are there any docs how to make detail view"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Professor and Ucenik instance to your view context.

```
context = {
    'professor': Professor.objects.get(),
    'ucenik': Ucenik.objects.get()
}
return render(request, context, 'url.html')
```

Comment: Okey i add this context to def profil(request, pk):

but when i refres page i get this problem: get() returned more than one Profesor -- it returned 5!

Comment: Yes - add it to any view you want to use {{ professor }} or {{ ucenik }} in the template. If your question is answered please mark this as answered.

Comment: i got this error: MultipleObjectsReturned at /profil/9/
get() returned more than one Profesor -- it returned 5!

Comment: You will have to define paramaters in the .get() to determine which professor or ucenik you want to display. for example Professor.objects.get(id=5) - or if you want to actually use the multiple results you can do Professor.objects.filter() or Professor.objects.all() instead.

This is all well documented in the Django documentation, I'd recommend checking it out. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: okey added 'profesor': Profesor.objects.all(),
                     'ucenik': Ucenik.objects.all()

and when: {{profesor.ime}} on profil.html page, nothing shows..

Comment: That's because you are now returning a queryset of objects rather than a single object like .get() does - if you want to go through all the professors in your template for example:
{% for prof in professor %}
    {{ prof.ime }}
{% endfor %}

I'd really recommend you read the documentation it will answer a lot of your questions probably.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your profile view dynamic by introducing an extra parameter which defines your role (i.e, Professor/Ucenik)

`/profil/profesor/2/` for profesor
`/profil/ucenik/1` for ucenik

```py
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns=[
    path('profil/<str:role>/<int:pk>/', views.profil, name='profil'),
]
```

```py
# views.py
from .models import Profesor,Ucenik # import your model
def profil(request,role,pk):
    context = {}
    context['role'] = type 
    if type=="profesor":
        context['person'] = Profesor.objects.get(id=pk)
    else:
        context['person'] = Ucenik.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'profil.html',context)
```

```html
<!-- profil.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<title>{{role}}</title>

{% block content %}

<body>
{% include 'navbar.html' %}

   <h1>Ime:</h1>
   {{person.ime}}
</body>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I recive this error:
Reverse for 'profil' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profil/(?P<role>[^/]+)/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Comment: I guess you tried to use links, in that case use `<a href={% url 'profil' profesor 1 %}>` tags. If not, update your **views** to receive the parameters from urls.

Answer (score 0):

**Different Approach:**
Assuming your `User` Model is having an `id` or any unique field.
You could use that `id` to be your profil id (i.e, url's `<int:pk`>).
so instead of `profil/profesor/3`, you can use `profil/3` which must be definitely one of two categories(assuming profesor and ucenik are mutually exclusive).

So in order to do that import User model into views along with other models.
**`views.py`**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from ..models import User # give correct path to user model
from .models import Profesor,Ucenik

def profil(request,pk):
    context={}
    person = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    
    try :
        person.profesor
        # print(dir(person))
    except Profesor.DoesNotExist:
        context['person'] = Ucenik.objects.get(id=person.ucenik.id)
    else:
        context['person'] = Profesor.objects.get(id=person.profesor.id)

    return render(request,"profil.html",context)
```

**`urls.py`**

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import profil

urlpatterns = [
    path('profil/<int:pk>/',profil) # I have used int
]
```

I used `person`,neutral variable name instead of profesor or ucenik.
You can name it anything even `profil`  
**`profil.html`**

```html
{{person.id}}
{{person.ime}}
{{person.prezime}}

{% if role == "ucenik" %}
  {{person.jmbg}}
{% else %}
  <!-- profesor does not have jmbg -->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This solved problem!